# How come gravity is $\mathcal{N}=8$? Why is graviton spin 2

Tags: gravity, quantum-spin, supersymmetry

I never understood why [supergravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%3D8_Supergravity) $\mathcal N=8$, nor why the spin of a [graviton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) is 2.

I've been reading around but I still don't have a back-of-the-envolope understanding.

Comment: Hi, welcome to this site. I don't think these two questions are related. If so, could you please split them up in two *separate* questions? Also, the question about the graviton has been asked before, see for instance [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39476/would-a-spin-2-particle-necessarily-have-to-be-a-graviton) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=graviton+spin+2) in general.

Comment: Actually they are related - it takes 8 supersymmetry transformations to go from the spin=+2 graviton to the spin=-2 graviton.

Comment: Regarding the graviton, see my answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108230/

Comment: On the $\mathcal N = 8$ part: This is just the *maximal* supergravity. There can be no more than 32 supercharges, because more supercharges would necessarily introduce higher spins than 2 into the theory - and we don't know how to deal with spins larger than 2. Smaller supergravities exist, though, see e.g. [mSuGra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity#mSUGRA)

Comment: This post (v2) asks two questions (instead of the recommended one question).