# Why does a spin O graviton predict a gas will be less gravitational when it is hot than when it is cold?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, particle-physics, gravity, quantum-gravity

My question is the title itself. .....  Why does a spin O graviton predict that a gas will be less gravitational when it is hot than when it is cold?

I know this contradicts observation, and that a quantum theory of gravity based on General Relativity will have a spin 2 graviton.

My question is about a spin O graviton that you would get by quantizing a scalar theory of gravity, such as Newton's or Nordstrom's.

Comment: You have to give links where this is claimed so one can evaluate it.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400871/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic  I googled for this 0 spin graviton, there is a   Horava-Lifshitz qft and it is not simple. to come to find predictions  needs a specific link ( let alone to answer why, which will have to do with the mathematical formulae)  see this https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0268

Comment: My reference for this question is: I read it in the introduction to " The Feynman Lectures On Gravitation" book, but it didn't explain it in a non-mathematical way.