# Why is the spin of the graviton 2?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-spin, quantum-gravity

Electromagnetic and gravitational interactions are similar - they are mediated by massless particles, they have infinite range and they diminish with $1/r^2$. The main difference is that gravity is always attractive while electromagnetic force is not.

A photon intermediating electromagnetic force has spin 1 while graviton should have spin 2. What is a reason for different spin values of photon and graviton?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108230, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39476

Comment: If what you casually state here is true, then why is physics struggling to define quantum gravity? 'The main difference is that gravity is always attractive while electromagnetic force is not.'

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton.

Comment: Gravitons are conjectured to be excitations of the metric field at the quantum level, thus it has the same spin as its field by definition.

Comment: Your question essentially boils down to "why is General Relativity (which predicts spin-2 gravitons) the correct description of gravity". The ultimate answer to this and similar questions is, of course, "because it works so well".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read off the fact that gravity is associated with spin-2 particles from the Einstein-Hilbert action?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108230/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, this is because spin-2 yields forces which are only attractive, as opposed to spin-1 which can mediate forces which are attractive or repulsive. I invite the experts to weigh in on this as I would like to understand this better myself. I'll delete my answer if a more complete one is furnished.