# Is Quantum spin greater than $1$ possible?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, elementary-particles, spin-statistics, higher-spin

I know that fermions have a spin of half of and bosons have a spin of 1 but at many places I have seen that their is written that spin for a boson can be 0,1,2....
Is there any physical meaning of spin greater than 1 or is it just a pridiction as to what possible spin magnitude can be.

Comment: Yes, there are high-spin fields. Graviton has spin 2. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-spin_theory

Comment: Are you only talking about elementary particles?

Comment: @Qmechanic yes sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we not have spin greater than 2?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14932/)

Comment: Graviton is *purely* hypothetic, but yes, there is no problem with having $s>1$