# Why masses attract each other?

Tags: gravity, mass, interactions

According to the gravitational law, every mass attracts each other.
But why the masses attract each other? Why they don't repel each other?

Comment: I think anything which contains **WHY** is a matter of philosophy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/

Answer (score 3):

Mass is gravity's equivalent of electric charge, with two obvious differences:

- Charges can be positive or negative, but masses are positive. We can discuss "what about the mass-energy stored in gravitational fields?" or any number of gotchas, but you and me and planets, as familiar examples, definitely have positive mass.
- If the dissimilarity ended there, you might expect masses to repel: after all, positive charges repel each other. Mathematically, we need to get a sign change from somewhere.

*Where* we get it from is a very complicated theoretical question. The first few chapters of *Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell* derive the mathematics, but here's the short version:

- Interactions are due to the exchange of particles of integer spin, coupling to a conserved tensor-valued current whose rank is that spin;
- Positive attracts positive if that spin is even, or repel if it's odd, because otherwise the action we minimise wouldn't have a kinetic cost, so would be unstable;
- The spin [has to be](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/why-do-we-not-have-spin-greater-than-2) $0$, $1$ or $2$;
- Electromagnetism is due to a spin-$1$ photon, coupling to a conserved vector current, so like charges repel;
- Gravity acts on all mass-energy contributions to the rank-$2$ [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), which requires a spin-$2$ graviton, which implies positive masses are attractive.