# Why don't elementary particles with spin $\frac{3}{2}$ exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin

The question is simple: why aren't there elementary particles to be found in Nature which have an intrinsic spin of $\frac{3}{2}$? Do the laws of physics (say, quantum field theory) prohibit their existence? Why shouldn't there be an intermediate value (between spin $1$ and $2$, both of which **do** exist)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the mathematical problems in introducing Spin 3/2 fermions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12647/)